# How to make the div float on the right of the page (affixed) using material design

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

So I am trying to create a layout where I have a page with cards, and a summary card on the right that floats affixed while I scroll. Kind of typical affix object that one has seen before with bootstrap. Here's my attempt so far: 
[image]

For some reason the first three cards treat the floating card as part of their row, and that adjusts their size. Is there a way to fix that? When I scroll i get the desired behavior:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<div class="container" layout="row" layout-xs="column">
    <div flex="20" hide-sm></div>
    <div flex>
        <h1 style="margin-bottom: 20px">Which edition?</h1>
    </div>
    <div flex="20" hide-sm></div>
</div>

<div sticky style="position: relative; float: right; z-index: 2;" flex="20">
    <div>
        <md-card ng-class="vm.selectedSupport === 'standard' ? 'card-3' : 'card-1'"
                 ng-click="vm.toggleSelectedSupport('standard')">
            <img src="images/priority_bw.jpg"
                 class="md-card-image"
                 alt="Washed Out"
                 ng-if="vm.selectedSupport !== 'standard'">
            <img src="images/priority.jpg"
                 class="md-card-image"
                 alt="Washed Out"
                 ng-if="vm.selectedSupport === 'standard'">
            <md-card-title layout="column" layout-align="center center">
                <md-card-title-text>
                    <span class="md-headline">I don't need priority support</span>
                </md-card-title-text>
            </md-card-title>
            <md-card-content layout="column" layout-align="center center">
                <p align="center">
                    over email only <br/>
                    within three working days
                </p>
                <h2>$0</h2>
            </md-card-content>
            <md-card-actions layout="column" layout-align="start">
                <md-button ng-class="vm.selectedSupport === 'standard' ? 'md-raised md-primary md-hue-1' : 'md-raised md-accent md-hue-1'">
                    Selected
                </md-button>
            </md-card-actions>
        </md-card>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="container" layout="row" layout-xs="column">
    <div flex="20" hide-sm></div>
    <div flex>
        <md-card ng-class="vm.selectedCard === 'card1' ? 'card-3' : 'card-1'"
                 ng-click="vm.toggleSelected('card1')">
            <img src="images/header_bw.jpg"
                 class="md-card-image"
                 alt="Washed Out"
                 ng-if="vm.selectedCard !== 'card1'">
            <img src="images/header.jpg"
                 class="md-card-image"
                 alt="Washed Out"
                 ng-if="vm.selectedCard === 'card1'">
            <md-card-title layout="column" layout-align="center center">
                <md-card-title-text>
                    <span class="md-headline">Free</span>
                </md-card-title-text>
            </md-card-title>
            <md-card-content layout="column" layout-align="center center">
                <p align="center">
                    This is the free version of the software that we are offering. It's not the full offering
                    so if you want more i will need to see some $$$.</p>
                <p>
                    Some tool 1 <br/>
                    Some tool 1 <br/>
                    Some tool 1 <br/>
                </p>
                <h2>Free</h2>
            </md-card-content>
            <md-card-actions layout="column" layout-align="start">
                <md-button ng-class="vm.selectedCard === 'card1' ? 'md-raised md-primary md-hue-1' : 'md-raised md-accent md-hue-1'">
                    Selected
                </md-button>
            </md-card-actions>
        </md-card>
    </div>
    <div flex>
        <md-card ng-class="vm.selectedCard === 'card2' ? 'card-3' : 'card-1'"
                 ng-click="vm.toggleSelected('card2')">
            <img src="images/header1_bw.jpg"
                 class="md-card-image"
                 alt="Washed Out"
                 ng-if="vm.selectedCard !== 'card2'">
            <img src="images/header1.jpg"
                 class="md-card-image"
                 alt="Washed Out"
                 ng-if="vm.selectedCard === 'card2'">
            <md-card-title layout="column" layout-align="center center">
                <md-card-title-text>
                    <span class="md-headline">Pro</span>
                </md-card-title-text>
            </md-card-title>
            <md-card-content layout="column" layout-align="center center">
                <p align="center">
                    This is the free version of the software that we are offering. It's not the full offering
                    so if you want more i will need to see some $$$.</p>
                <p>
                    Some tool 1 <br/>
                    Some tool 1 <br/>
                    Some tool 1 <br/>
                </p>
                <h2>$9.99/month</h2>
            </md-card-content>
            <md-card-actions layout="column" layout-align="start">
                <md-button ng-class="vm.selectedCard === 'card2' ? 'md-raised md-primary md-hue-1' : 'md-raised md-accent md-hue-1'">
                    Selected
                </md-button>
            </md-card-actions>
        </md-card>
    </div>
    <div flex>
        <md-card ng-class="vm.selectedCard === 'card3' ? 'card-3' : 'card-1'"
                 ng-click="vm.toggleSelected('card3')">
            <img src="images/header2_bw.jpg"
                 class="md-card-image"
                 alt="Washed Out"
                 ng-if="vm.selectedCard !== 'card3'">
            <img src="images/header2.jpg"
                 class="md-card-image"
                 alt="Washed Out"
                 ng-if="vm.selectedCard === 'card3'">
            <md-card-title layout="column" layout-align="center center">
                <md-card-title-text>
                    <span class="md-headline">Enterprise</span>
                </md-card-title-text>
            </md-card-title>
            <md-card-content layout="column" layout-align="center center">
                <p align="center">
                    This is the free version of the software that we are offering. It's not the full offering
                    so if you want more i will need to see some $$$.</p>
                <p>
                    Some tool 1 <br/>
                    Some tool 1 <br/>
                    Some tool 1 <br/>
                </p>
                <h2>$19.99/month</h2>
            </md-card-content>
            <md-card-actions layout="column" layout-align="start">
                <md-button ng-class="vm.selectedCard === 'card3' ? 'md-raised md-primary md-hue-1' : 'md-raised md-accent md-hue-1'">
                    Selected
                </md-button>
            </md-card-actions>
        </md-card>
    </div>
    <div flex="20" hide-sm></div>
</div>
<div class="container" layout="row" layout-xs="column">
    <div flex="20" hide-sm></div>
    <div flex>
        <h1 style="margin-bottom: 5px;">How many users?</h1>
        <h4 style="margin: 0; color: grey;">
            <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
            Buy more than 5 and get 5% discount
        </h4>
        <h4 style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 20px; color: grey;">
            <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
            Buy more than 50 and get 10% discount
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div flex="20" hide-sm></div>
</div>
<div class="container" layout="row" layout-xs="column">
    <div flex="20" hide-sm></div>
    <div flex>
        <div class="container" layout="row" layout-align="center center">
            <md-button class="md-fab md-primary md-hue-1"
                       aria-label="Eat cake"
                       ng-click="vm.count = (vm.count - 1) < 0 ? 0 : vm.count -1">
                <md-icon class="fas fa-minus"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
            <md-input-container>
                <input type="text"
                       title=""
                       aria-label="count-input"
                       style="text-align: center; width: 120px; height: 60px; font-size: 48px;"
                       ng-model="vm.count">
            </md-input-container>
            <md-button class="md-fab md-primary md-hue-1"
                       aria-label="Eat cake"
                       ng-click="vm.count = vm.count + 1">
                <md-icon class="fas fa-plus"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div flex>
        <div class="container" layout="column" layout-align="center center">
            <p ng-if="vm.count < 50">Save <b>{{vm.count < 5 ? 5 : 10}}%</b> when you upgrade to <br/>
                {{vm.count < 5 ? 5 : 50}} licenses
            </p>
            <md-button class="md-raised md-primary md-hue-1"
                       ng-click="vm.setCount()"
                       style="width: 50%"
                       ng-if="vm.count < 50">
                Upgrade to {{vm.count < 5 ? 5 : 50}}
            </md-button>
            <h2 ng-if="vm.count >= 50" layout-align="center center" layout="column">
                <i class="fas fa-check fa-2x" style="color: green"></i>
                Awesome! You are saving 10%
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div flex="20" hide-sm></div>
</div>
```

The sticky directive is a following:

```
angular.module('MonkeyBarsApp').directive('sticky', Sticky);

Sticky.$inject = ['$mdSticky'];

function Sticky($mdSticky) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            $mdSticky(scope, element);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. 
Something that I am trying to mimick: https://studio3t.com/buy/

Answer (score 0):

this is Jake, I built the page that you are referencing on https://studio3t.com/buy.

If I understand correctly, you're finding that the floating sidebar is affecting the width of the 3 product boxes, correct? My markup is different, but I can explain to you how I've laid out my page:

The sidebar is in the same row as the product boxes:

```
<div class="row content-container">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-9 p-4">...</div> <!-- content column -->
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 p-0">...</div> <!-- sidebar column -->
</div>
```

So this parent row holds columns with a 3/4 + 1/4 split (col-lg-9 + col-lg-3). The product boxes are each contained inside a nested row > then a col-12 div to wrap them > each of them is set to col-md-4:

[image]

[image]

My first guess with the product boxes at the top is that they are set to an incorrect width - if you have a codepen example I could inspect the code with dev tools. The fixed position sidebar shouldn't affect the width of the other boxes - it is 'outside the flow' of the page.

However, it's possible the plugin / code you're using sets the position of the sidebar to relative at first, and only changes it to fixed on scroll - therefore the width of the sidebar while it is relatively positioned may be affecting the product boxes.

In terms of having the element affixed, it looks as though you're using Angular 1.5 (I'm only familiar with 2+ and actually built the Studio 3T page with VueJS). To have the sidebar affix itself on scroll I'm using a plugin called Vue Affix. It detects scroll events and then changes the style of the selected element (the sidebar) to position: fixed and top: 160px (the top value is an arbitrary option):

[image]

Let me know if any of that helps!

Good luck,

Jake